# Power Bi - Order Fulfillmernt Matrix - 14 day Quantities Due & Quantities Remaining Calculations

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

I'm hoping someone may be able to help with this quite complex (to me) process.

I have a matrix that details order quantities with quantities in stock. I'm wanting to perform this calculation over a 14 day period.  I think the image I've created below helps to describe this problem.

[image]

My starting point was to perform some merging of the two tables in Power Query to possibly reduce the requirement of complex DAX coding, however i'm now wondering if a pure DAX solution is better?

Also worth noting this example only considers one product, the logic is required to be applied to all products from the catalogue.

I'm hoping I've explained my problem fully and someone can help to point me in the right direction.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Powerquery in M code. Can paste into home..advanced editor...

The basic trick is just grouping on Product and then taking running total of usage as compared to starting balance

code for Table1:

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
Starting =  Table.Group(Table2, {"Product"}, {{"Qty", each List.Sum([Qty]), type number}}),
#"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(Source, {"Product"}, Starting, {"Product"}, "Table2", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
#"Expanded Table" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "Table2", {"Qty"}, {"Qty"}),
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Expanded Table", {"Product"}, {{"data", each 
    let #"Added Index"=Table.AddIndexColumn(_, "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type),
    #"Added Total" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Index", "CumTotal", each List.Sum(List.FirstN(#"Added Index"[Qty Ordered],[Index]))??0)
    in Table.AddColumn(#"Added Total", "AvailToProduce", each List.Max({0,List.Min({[Qty Ordered],[Qty]-[CumTotal]})})), type table}}),
#"Expanded data" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "data", {"Day", "AvailToProduce"}, {"Day", "AvailToProduce"}),
filler = Table.ExpandListColumn(#table({"Product", "Day","AvailToProduce"},{{ #"Expanded data"[Product]{0},{0..14},0}}), "Day"),
#"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Expanded data" & filler,{{"Day", Order.Ascending}}),
#"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Sorted Rows", {{"Day", type text}}, "en-US"), List.Distinct(Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Sorted Rows", {{"Day", type text}}, "en-US")[Day]), "Day", "AvailToProduce", List.Sum)
in  #"Pivoted Column"
```

[image]

Comment: Great. Feel free to upvote if you think this can help someone else by toggling up arrow on answer